# protobuf-net serialize complex type (class) as scalar

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

Does anyone know if there is a way how to serialize complex types as scalar values using [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)?

I have a dozen or so of value-objects like:

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;

public sealed class Id /*: IEquatable<Id>*/
{
    public Id(byte[] id)
    {
        // some validation

        Value = id.ToImmutableArray();
    }

    public ImmutableArray<byte> Value { get; }

    // overriden Equals, GetHashCode, ToString, some operators, etc.
}
```

(I had simplified the type as much as possible)

These types are properties in actual contracts.
I would like to achieve their serialization/deserialization as underlying scalar value. So for code above that would be somehow hooking into serialization process with:

```
Func<Id, byte[]> serialize = id => id.Value.ToArray();
Func<byte[], Id> deserialize = bytes => new Id(bytes);
```

using something like [JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) in Newtonsoft JSON.NET or any other way that would archieve the mapping.

I have already checked serialization surrogates through registration in RuntimeTypeModel. It is close, but not quite (it's good for class-class mapping, not so much class-scalar value).

Comment: The short version would be "no that isn't currently supported" - however, if limited to `byte[]` (c#) and `bytes` (.proto) it could potentially be added...